# What do all the colored dots on the minimap mean?

Tags: the-witcher-2

On the minimap you can occasionally see red, green and blue dots. The red ones are enemies, but what do the other two mean? Merchants and craftsmen are marked with icons, what do the blue and green colored dots stand for?

[image]

Comment: I don't have the game, but what do you see when you're actually on top of one...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Green dots are allies.

Blue dots are people of interest or quest-related non-hostile NPCs.

Comment: What exactly means ally? I've seen it for more or less random NPCs.

Comment: Ally is a person who is on your side in case of a hostile situation.

Answer (score 4):

Green stands for friendly.

Blue for neutral.

Red for hostile.

Those are not necessarily important persons. For example the kids are marked as green dots on the map but you can't really interact with them.

Comment: That's good to know :-)